# Scoring Attractions in Ticket to Ride: New York

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring, ticket-to-ride-new-york

I recently bought the new version of Ticket to Ride New York. One thing that is slightly unclear is the scoring rules on routes between two tourist attractions.
(Sorry if that is incorrect, but I don't have the English rules here and that is the exact translation from my language)

Anyways say you build the route between Times Square -> Empire State Building -> Chelsea.
- You get 1 point for the route TS -> ESB.
- You get 2 points for the route ESB -> C.
But then according to the rules you get one point per tourist attraction you connect.

Does that mean:
3 points (one for each)
or
4 points (2 points TS -> ESB and 2 points ESB -> C)

Image for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules say

> Finally, each player scores one point for each 
>   Tourist Attraction that is connected to one or more 
>   of the Routes they claimed.

In your example, there are three Tourist Attractions connected to at least one your routes, so you get three points from Tourist Attractions.